# Is there a way to capture just my main display

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, monitoring

so I'm using this application called time clock wizard that takes screenshot of my desktop at different intervals for the client to see. I was just wondering if there was a way to somehow make it capture just my main display, the reason behind is I do work for another client which I usually do on my second monitor and they're mostly private information like NDA's and other legal documents that I can't have my time clock wizard capturing. Is there any application or trick that I can use to somehow make this work? Thanks a lot, it would be a lot of help.

Comment: yes they know, which is why we're trying to figure out how to capture just the screen I use for them so they don't have to crop out the screenshot of the other monitor for their reports.

Comment: Silly question but have you contacted and asked them directly?

Comment: I have, I asked if they could check on their end if there's a setting they could change but apparently there isn't there's only an option to display the full screenshot but not just for one screen